# Embeded google map, remove points

Tags: javascript

I have an embed google map on a webpage not programmed by me, I need to figure out how to remove 2 of the 22 points (blue markers) on the map that when you click on show the address. Is it just a snipit of code somewhere in the HTML or JavaScript? or is it protected by a google account?

```
<iframe width="666" height="325" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/speciallink"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you post the code used to embed the map?  I've seen this done just using the embed code in the HTML (certainly not in the CSS).

Comment: I just found it its in an iframe, does that change things?

Comment: presumably the key is in the <speciallink> part - there is no logging in to an account here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by logging into the google account that created the map, and then editing the points. Hope this helps someone out there.